# USB installer: “ Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed”

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, 20.04, initramfs

I am currently trying to install Ubuntu as a Dual boot to my Windows.

I have created a USB-installer using Rufus and the downlodable iso from Ubuntu's own website.

However, when I boot my computer with the USB, and select Ubuntu through the grub loader, I am stuck with the error: “Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed”, while some of my screen is flickering.

I have afterwards tried to boot my laptop using the same bootable USB, and are not met with the error on the laptop.

Does anyone know how i should proceed? Or have anyone also encountered this?

Comment: When booting to the Ubuntu Live USB, does the self-check pass without error?

Comment: Status please...

Comment: This maybe related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1835660   (thanks @vmclark)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's kind of a bogus error, unless you can't fully boot into Ubuntu.

Either boot into **Ubuntu**, or into **Recovery Mode** from the GRUB menu...

- GRUB menu

  - Additional Options

    - Recovery Mode

      - Root Access

...and type the following commands. This will rebuild the (possibly) broken ramdisk file.

`sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)`

`reboot`

Comment: I can't find "Additional options" in Grub menu on 20.04 live server USB pendrive I made with Rufus... Where to look for this menu?

Comment: @Marecky Are you running a Desktop or Server installation? If Server, then the instructions are different. If you can still boot, you can do the `update-initramfs` command from a terminal or root prompt.

Comment: It's server installation. I can't boot because the error pops up on the beginning of the process

Comment: @Marecky Can you boot to an older kernel?

Comment: I don't have other kernels on this USB installation media. I just used Rufus to write ISO to the USB stick

Comment: @Marecky Sorry, no, I meant an older kernel on your normal boot media. Since it's a server, I can't tell you how to do that. If you CAN figure out how to boot to an older kernel, then you can use a modified version of my `update-initramfs` to fix your problem.

Comment: On my normal boot media I have Windows 10. I want to do almost the same thing as the OP. I want to dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu Server 20.04

Comment: @Marecky I'm a little confused. Don't you have Ubuntu Server installed now? Are you getting the decompress error when booting from the Ubuntu Live USB, or your primary boot media? Even if you see the error, does it boot up fully?

Comment: I managed to resolve my issue, I changed some BIOS settings and swapped SATA cables. The error message didn't go away, nor installer got halted, so I could carry on with installation.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem just by selecting mode `Ubuntu Safe Graphics` when it started.
https://linuxmint-installation-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/boot_options.html
Took a few seconds to see the Ubuntu landing section.

Comment: This was also my issue. Something to do with my graphics card and its drivers.

Comment: Nvidia giving problems with Linux since ages ... "Nvidia, F**k You" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYWzMvlj2RQ&ab_channel=SiliconNews

Comment: No Nvidia card present, but that was the solution. (Ubuntu Server)

Comment: ha ha ha ha ha ha... Linus no likey NVIDIA!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add one more thing to this.

I just ended up here for the same error message while trying to provision a VM on MS-HyperV 2019.

In my case it wasn't even completing the verification correctly, after a bit of digging and messing around it turned out I had not allocated enough memory to the VM instance.

As I do with all my VM's I use dynamic memory, and I'd set the startup amount to 256mb.  Because this was happening so early in the boot HyperV wasn't getting anough chance to profile the memory demand properly and re-size it as needed.

As soon as I upped the start-up memory to 2gb and rebooted from the ISO image I was using, everything started to work ok.

Comment: This is a common problem.  By increasing the system RAM for an Ubuntu 20.04 ARM based ISO install to 2 GB solved this issue.  Modern OSes need the RAM -- especially newer Ubuntu distros

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue when setting up **Ubuntu 20.04** on my **Dell PC**.

I downloaded the ISO image and then burnt it into a USB Flash drive using **Rufus**, when I tried to install, I got the error

> Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed

I also tried using **UNetbootin** to burn the Ubuntu 20.04 ISO file into the USB Flash drive, but it gave me the same error.

The issue can be caused by more than one factor. For me it was:

- Intel(R) RST was enabled, that is, Redundant Array of Independent Disks (RAID)
- BitLocker was turned for my **Windows C: Drive** which I wanted to install Ubuntu alongside

**Here's how I fixed it**:

We will need to turn off Bitlocker for Ubuntu to be able to access the files in the **Windows C: Drive**, and then we will also need to change the storage controller protocol from **RST** (Redundant Array of Independent Disks - **RAID**) to Advanced Host Controller Interface (**AHCI**):

- Boot into your Windows operating system
- Click on start and type manage BitLocker and launch it as an administrator.
- Click on Turn off BitLocker (wait on the decryption to finish – it is indicated in the system tray)
- Reboot your computer to make sure BitLocker is disabled.
- Right-click the Windows Start Menu and click on Command Prompt (Admin).
- Enter: `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal`
- Reboot the computer into the BIOS  (F2,Del,ESC,F12 or other key depending on the computer manufacturer).
- Look for **SATA operation mode** and change it to **AHCI** and save + reboot computer. (F10 key etc.)
- Windows should start up in safemode.
- Right-click the Windows Start Menu and click on Command Prompt (Admin).
- Enter: `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot`
- Reboot computer and windows should start up normally again.

Now you can install Ubuntu 20.04 without issues.

**Resources**:

- [Ubuntu installation on computers with Intel(R) RST enabled](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347)
- [Switch to AHCI mode in windows 10 with BitLocker enabled](https://vrpc.com/windows/switch-to-ahci-mode-in-windows-10-with-bitlocker-enabled/)
- [Ubuntu installation on computers running Windows and BitLocker turned on](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-running-windows-and-bitlocker-turned-on/15338)
- [Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed?](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/fkn287/initramfs_unpacking_failed_decoding_failed/)

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: I also made USB stick with 20.04 (server) with Rufus, but I had no luck reproducing your steps. AHCI was already on, Bitlocker was already off... My PC is custom parts, 4790k, 16GB Ram, GTX 1080

Comment: Do you get the same error like the one in the question?

Comment: Of cource, and I want to do almost the same thing, I want to install Ubuntu Server 20.04 dual-boot with Windows 10.

Comment: I could offer to help as much as I can over a call. We could schedule a zoom meeting or Google meeting so that we look through it together.

Comment: I managed to resolve my issue, I changed some BIOS settings and swapped SATA cables. The error message didn't go away, nor installer got halted, so I could carry on with installation.

Comment: That's amazing. Goodluck then.