# Does: "Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed" mean I have a bad installation?

Tags: nvidia, initramfs

I see that the reference message has spawned several previous posts. I installed 20.04 a couple of weeks ago. I read that the message is meaningless. (I followed the link in a response to one of the relevant posts.)

I would like to get a better sense of the potential that the multi-day effort to get my 20.04 installation productive will be fruitful.

Does this message mean I should re-install 20.04, after recreating a live USB?

Thanks,
Tim

JIC: A brief history of when I noticed the message.

After fixing a display resolution issue (Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers -> selecting an NVIDIA driver), I started installing software. For some reason the 20.04 installer chose the Nouveau driver from X.org.

After a largish software update (20.04 -> 20.04.1?), the low resolution problem returned, along with system freezes at the motherboard splash screen. I have no idea if there is an association. This happened yesterday.

I was able to re-fix the resolution problem, by again selecting an NVIDIA driver after a (fortunate) successful startup. For some reason the "driver" selected  (Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers) had changed to "Manually installed driver" instead of an NVIDIA driver, or the Nouveau driver.

During the several reboots (a couple of them hard), I noticed that the reference message appears on each boot. I do not know if it appeared before my noticing it yesterday.

Comment: Hmm... You can look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269855/usb-installer-initramfs-unpacking-failed-decoding-failed). That *may* get you sorted out.

Comment: It is true it is an error you can ignore UNLESS you cant fully boot, but give rebuilding a whirl, first boot into recovery and issue these commands: sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r) and then sudo reboot

Comment: Thank you. I tried the suggested commands. I still get the message. NOTE that response to the first command you suggested included 3 lines: line 1: "The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sdb2." line 2: UUID info. line 3: "Set the Resume variable to override this."

Comment: Additionally, sdb2 is a linux-swap that I set up for my 18.04 installation, which I retain.  20.04 is on /dev/sdb5 and /dev/sdb6, under extended partition /dev/sdb3.  I was led to believe that I did not need to set up explicit swap space when I installed 20.04. What gives?

Comment: A key question is: Does the reference message relate to my swap? I do computations/simulations, and use a swap partition. (The same size as my RAM - 32 GB.) So, it would be great if the 20.04 installation can use the swap partition I set up for 18.04. I would not have to set up a partition for 20.o4.

Answer (score 0):

**It is best to ignore the message because it's quite meaningless**

If you want to remove it, open `initramfs.conf` (it is located at `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf`) with `sudo vim initramfs.conf`.

Look for the line with something along the lines of `COMPRESS=...`.

If "..." says `lz4`, interchange it with `gzip`.

If "..." says `gzip`, interchange it with `lz4`.

After doing so, update your ramdisk by copying this into a terminal: `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Then, reboot your computer.

However, it's best to simply ignore the message, as doing the above steps may or may not slow down boot time.

This is possibly because `lz4` is faster at decompression than `gzip`.