# Install Ubuntu20.04 in Dell(ALIENWARE M17 2020):

Tags: grub2, usb, 20.04, dell

I want to install ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop

I follow the steps on the official Tutorials: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Especially, in my first try, I changed the **SATA** from **RAID** to **AHCI** and disable **Secure Boot**

But, when I boot my computer with the usb, and select ubuntu through the grub loader, the screen appeared as follows

[first try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp3nV.jpg)

Then, I follow the steps in the link: [USB installer: “ Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269855/usb-installer-initramfs-unpacking-failed-decoding-failed/1279704#1279704?newreg=46aa18acc11a489d95cb7c3a0184ef4b). Unfortunately, I could not find the **BitLocker** in my **Dell**, but I disable the **Firware TPM** in BIOS. Lastly, when I try install Ubuntu, the screen appeared as follows:
[second try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbdqF.jpg)

Comment: Judging by your graphics in those images, you may next face the hurdle of graphics (when you get past this hurdle) and need to try things like nomodset as a boot parameter. Anyhow, also make sure you verify your downloaded .iso. A helpful trick is to download it as a torrent, which automatically verifies the download.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I strong recommended this https://www.balena.io/etcher/ for usb boot, then installing boot on your laptop, with UEFI, let know me if it is working for you.

Comment: No. I find my issue. Maybe, the Ubuntu dose not support RTX2060 Well. And, I find some steps to add "nomodeset" in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I find a funny.

In my second try, when I close my laptop (This means my screen touch my keyboard) and open it, the install will display.

However, the installation will freeze.

My GPU is 2060